# How to use 2 columns in an index in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I used to have this code working

```
df_features = df_features.pivot(index='RepID', columns='Customer', values='Frequency')
```

but dataframe has changed and become 2 keys instead of 1

So I changed it as following

```
df_features = df_features.pivot(index=['RepID', 'CountryID'], columns='Customer', values='Frequency')
```

but this creates this error

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 60466, index implies 2.

How to resolve this error

**Sample Data**

```
101 201 Ali 33
101 201 Tom 44
101 202 Kin 11
101 202 Tom 55
102 201 May 58
102 201 Kin 38
103 201 Tom 98
```

Comment: How about pass some sample data.

Comment: @xcodz-dot provided

Comment: Try passing the actual columns instead of the column names: `df_features.pivot(index=df_features[['RepID', 'CountryID']], columns='Customer', values='Frequency')`

Comment: @ayhan does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the result you expect, but I think a pivot table can do the work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data={'RepID':[101,101,101,101,102,102,103,103],
    'CountryID':[201,201,202,202,201,201,201,201],
    'Customer':['Ali','Tom','Kin','Tom','May','Kin','Tom','Tom'],
    'Frequency':[33,44,11,55,58,38,98,10000]}

df_features=pd.DataFrame(data)

#df_features = df_features.pivot(index=['RepID', 'CountryID'], columns='Customer', values='Frequency')
df_features = pd.pivot_table(data=df_features,index=['RepID', 'CountryID'], columns='Customer', values='Frequency',aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)

print(df_features)
```

result:

```
Customer         Ali  Kin  May    Tom
RepID CountryID
101   201         33    0    0     44
      202          0   11    0     55
102   201          0   38   58      0
103   201          0    0    0  10098
```